# send integer type params in json as ajax request using jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js

Am trying to send integer type data in json and retrive in server side

in client side am sending in below code

```
var userID = readCookie("user_id");
  var data = {
    "id": parseInt(userID),
    "password": $("#password").val()
  };
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "/changePassword",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
      $("#errLabel").html('Password changed successfully')
    }
  });
```

And in server side while i trying to print data am getting as

```
 { id: '1', password: 'qwer' }
```

actually am sending id as integer format but in server side am getting this as string.

How can i retrive    `{ id: 1, password: 'qwer' }`.i want to pass this data to update a database.so i cant change it as `{ id: parseInt('1'), password: 'qwer' }.`
In database id are stored in integer form.so due this problem cant update the `db` also.

```
helper.update(context.db.Signups, data,  function(err, res) {
console.log(res)
 callback(null, {res:true});
 });
```

Comment: why can't you parse it to int on the server side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add processData : false to the options section of your .ajax call.